# how to open a bootstrap4 popup on window load if the a php session variable is not set?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I want to open a `bootstrap4` popup on window load event if the `php` session variable is not set.

```
 session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['templateid'])){
         // open popup code 
    }
```

how can I do this on window on load event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can create a variable that will serve as a flag for opening the pop up, something like this:

```
session_start();
$openPopup = (!isset($_SESSION['templateid'])) ? true : false;
```

then use the value of `$openPopup` to check whether to open the popup or not in your script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var openPopup = <?php echo $openPopup ?>;
    if(openPopup) {
        //open popup here
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: let me try your solution